# Remove file - Read only file from device

Tags: ios5, nsfilemanager

I create a file with attribute NSFileappendonly, i am thinking this is enough to create readonly file in ios.My problem is try to remove the file from device it returns error.Please anyone help me..

Comment: What method are using to delete the file?

Answer (score 0):

A 513 states you do not have permission to write to that folder [NSFileWriteNoPermissionError](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html). You need to make sure you are only trying to write to one of the 3 folders in your app's dir (Documents, Temp, or Cache). Generally you use the Documents folder. (Trying to write directly to the main bundle can cause the error you are having)

[iOS Environment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW1)

You can remove a file with NSFileManager but only if your app is signed and you are attempting to remove from one of the 3 allowed folders. Those 3 folders are only accessible by your app.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *yourFile = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFile.txt"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:yourFile error:NULL];
```

Comment: I used like this,but i got error from removeItemAtPath Method.error description is operation not permitted ,cocoa error 513.